# Custom order for php array based on indexes

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have PHP array that looks like

```
$my_arr['cats'] = array('Shadow', 'Tiger', 'Luna');
$my_arr['dogs'] = array('Buddy', 'Lucy', 'Bella');
$my_arr['dolphins'] = array('Sunny', 'Comet', 'Pumpkin');
$my_arr['lizzards'] = array('Apollo', 'Eddie', 'Bruce');
//and many more lines like this
```

I need to sort it based on it keys using sorting array like

```
$order = array('lizzards', 'cats');
```

I want that the first item should be **lizzards** array, second item - **cats** and then all items that were not specified in $order array. How it can be done using usort / uasort / uksort functions?

Comment: You're looking for multi array sort? http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php

Comment: No, i don't need sorting for inner arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by below code

```
<?php

function sortByKey(&$arr,$key_order)
{
    if(count(array_intersect(array_keys($arr),$key_order))!=count($key_order))
    {
        return false;
    }
    $ordered_keys=array_merge($key_order,array_diff(array_keys($arr),$key_order));
    $sorted_arr=[];
    foreach($ordered_keys as $key)
    {
        $sorted_arr[$key]=$arr[$key];
    }
    $arr=$sorted_arr;
    return true;
}

$my_arr=[];
$my_arr['cats'] = array('Shadow', 'Tiger', 'Luna');
$my_arr['dogs'] = array('Buddy', 'Lucy', 'Bella');
$my_arr['dolphins'] = array('Sunny', 'Comet', 'Pumpkin');
$my_arr['lizzards'] = array('Apollo', 'Eddie', 'Bruce');

$order = array('lizzards', 'cats');

if(sortByKey($my_arr,$order){
    echo "Sorting done successfully";
}
else
{
    echo "Sorting ignored, order element miss matched";
}

print_r($my_arr);
?>
```

Comment: Good one; only caveat: this requires that all order keys are present in `$my_arr`. If that's not guaranteed you need to throw a check in for that.

Comment: @deceze, if you run this code - you can see that it is sorting full array with only two items specified in order array

Comment: @deceze, I have made change also that case, if order key is mismatch then return false

Comment: @moonvader I'm pointing out an issue with the other way around: if not all values in `$order` are actually present as keys in `$my_arr`.

Comment: @Haresh Maybe a simple `if (isset($arr[$key]))` in the loop would be better, but that depends on how this function is supposed to behave exactly…

Comment: but I have thought if any key is miss matched then no meaning of sort array as if we use isset() then skip whole element in sorted array

Comment: That's actually the behaviour I would expect. You give it a *preferred order*, but if some elements don't exist then you can still order the rest perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

A shorter solution using uksort:

```
uksort($my_arr, function ($a,$b) use ($order) {
    //Look for elements indexes in the 'order' array 
    $aKey = array_search($a, $order);
    $bKey = array_search($b, $order);

    if($aKey !== FALSE && $bKey !== FALSE) {
        return $aKey - $bKey;
    } else if($aKey !== FALSE) {
        return -1;
    } else if($bKey !== FALSE) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to employ a sorting algorithm at all.

If you know that the nominated elements will exist in your master array, then create an array with the leading elements' keys, then place your master array onto of that.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/07sc4))

```
var_export(array_replace(array_flip($order), $my_arr));
```

or

```
var_export(array_merge(array_flip($order), $my_arr));
```